# GWT - Styling the dialog box with custom styles

Tags: gwt, styles

I have built a custom dialog box. All the functionality is just working fine but only one thing is frustrating me a lot. I have set custom style class to this dialog box. It works perfectly fine in IE but when using chrome browser i do not see my styles being applied.

Like for example - I have the background color of the dialog box as black and border of color black. I do not see any of these styles when i use chrome.

Can anyone help me figure out whats going on here ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome has some excellent debugging tools. For instance, you can right click on an element in your dialog box and choose "Inspect element". On the right it will give you a complete breakdown of how CSS styles were applied to it.

From here you can debug why an element is styled the way it is.  You'll notice strange CSS styles named things like "FJDLKSJFLKDSJF". These are styles that GWT created, usually in a UIBinder layout.  Other styles will be named things like "GWT-DecoratedPanel". These styles are styles that are used to theme GWT widgets and can be over-ridden.

Without seeing your specific CSS, it's hard to help any further than these hints.